# how to read a java object from android resources

Tags: android, android-resources

I am still new to android and there is probably an obvious answer to my problem. But I have not found the correct question to ask or google for.

What I want to do is read in a xml representation of a (list of) java object(s) and have the objects accessible from my activity.

Is this possible with android resources? 
After some reading through the internets the best solution I found was to write the objects as json string and save them in res/values.
And then use something like Gson to parse them as java objects.

But there has to be a better way.
What would be the standard way to approach this?

To add some context: I am programming a small android game and would like to have a research-tree.
Each research item has properties like a name, costs, effects and of course a list of references to other research items as preconditions.

I would appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: I obviously am new to asking questions on stackoverflow as well. 
The Question was somehow postet before I was finished writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use 3rd party solutions, the recommended way is to use the platform's `XmlPullParser`:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: additional Information that would have helped me as well:
You can store your xml File in res/xml. 
getResources().getXml(R.xml.<filename>) will give you a Parser that implements the suggested XmlPullParser